# Is there anyway to add a php views counter numbers on the thumb?

Tags: php, view, counter

Well. I searched on web but i couldn't find that script, what i found was a php script that gives you the views counter on separated page, on a list is there anyway to add maybe a bootstrap thumbnail and on the description the number of the views per click? Thanks anyway.

Ps: im not trying to get this done i'm working on it while im asking this question, just to make things easier. Two minds is better than one

Comment: This question is way to broad for the Stack Overflow site. Please try to create something and when you run into an error or something post that in a new question.

Comment: Yes!! I will, i'm trying to find a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to create an image in php. Something like that.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = "Test image";
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Then, you should count image views and add them on the image in the same way like `$string="Test image";`

Comment: Thanks;-),  let me try this

Comment: Thanks my code wasnt so right